# Rest Client android with Amazon EC2

Tags: android, web-services, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am doing a REST client in Android to consume a webService hosted in Amazon EC2.

When a acess the URL in bowser, it's work fine. But when i tried to acess the webservice in the android app, i received a error 404.

```
            URL urla = new URL(SERVICE_URL);

            HttpGet method= new HttpGet(new URI(SERVICE_URL));
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(SERVICE_URL));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

When I provide the rule "All" Access In the amazon EC2, it's work fine, but i believe it's not a better way.

**All Rule:**

*Ports: All

Protocol: All

Source: All*

Does anyone know a better way to access the REST webservice hosted in the EC2 with a client  android?

Comment: You see the 404 in the responseCode? The response is right or it is a 404 page? I recommend you using this library project for calling APIS. It allows you an easy implementation, clean code and many possibilities. I hope this would help you. https://github.com/matessoftwaresolutions/AndroidHttpRestService

Answer (score 0):

Try using AsyncHttpClient library instead thats simple and easy. Here is a sample code

```
AsyncHttpClient client;
client.get("http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/MyService1/jaxrs/helloworld",
        new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        // When the response returned by REST has Http
        // response code '200'
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            try {
                // JSON Object
                tv1.setText(response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                tv1.setText(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Simple give the public DNS of your instance with port of server, then path to the function call of your service.
This is how I did it.